# What explains the results of rank() function on a negative numerical vector?

Tags: r

```
x1 <- c(3, 1, 4, 15, 92)
rank(x1)
[1] 2 1 3 4 5

-x1
[1]  -3  -1  -4 -15 -92

rank(-x1)
[1] 4 5 3 2 1
```

Why doesn't rank(-x1) give 5,4,3,1,2 as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function would be `order` instead of `rank`

```
order(-x1)
#[1] 5 4 3 1 2
```

We can also get to the same output as `rank` if we do `order` twice

```
order(order(-x1))
#[1] 4 5 3 2 1
```

---

Also, the `rank` output depends on the `ties.method` and if there are any duplicates.  It can take a value of `"average", "first", "last", "random", "max", "min"`.

Answer (score 1):

Because -92 is the smallest number and so on. -1 is the largest one, hence rank 5.